# Free API for speech recognition system

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am looking for a free speech recognition API to use in my application which gives best results.On Googling I found few including Windows Speech Recognition Macros.But my application's task is to perform better than Windows Speech Recognition System.So do you, as a programmer,aware of a very good Speech Recognition System.

I found similar questions on SO but they deal with different scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest CMU's Sphinx system. See http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net. It has tools to tune language and acoustic models, which can increase accuracy. There are multiple versions, but I would begin with PocketSphinx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the J.A.R.V.I.S. Java Speech API.

https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api

Comment: it's not free...you need google speech API access token to use it